# Does SetupDiGetClassDevs work with device instance IDs as documented?

Tags: windows, winapi, device, hardware-interface, setupapi

According to MSDN documentation, [SetupDiGetClassDevs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms792959.aspx) can be passed a [device instance ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567984.aspx) to obtain a [device information set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms791129.aspx) for a specific device:

> To return only a specific device, set
>   the DIFCF_DEVICEINTERFACE flag and use
>   the Enumerator parameter to supply the
>   device instance ID of the device.

I get the device instance ID by parsing the symbolic name from the [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(VS.85).aspx) message [`DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363205(VS.85).aspx) event, and I have verified the resulting ID by comparing it to that returned from [SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms792990.aspx). Even passing the OS supplied device instance ID does not work (i.e. the SetupDiGetClassDevs call fails with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`).

My current workaround to fetch a [`SP_DEVINFO_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms792997.aspx) structure for the newly arrived device is to enumerate all devices in the same class and compare the result of SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId to the symbolic name. However, I don't see why this should be necessary according to the documentation...

Has anyone gotten SetupDiGetClassDevs to work in this way? Is there a better method for getting further information for a device using data in the DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL event?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you have to either specify the `DIGCF_ALLCLASSES` flag to find all classes that match the given device instance id, or else specify the ClassGuid and use the `DIGCF_DEFAULT` flag.

This worked for me:

```
void error(DWORD err)
{
    WCHAR buf[0x200];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, err, 0, buf, 0x200, NULL);
    wprintf(L"%x: %s\n", err,  buf);
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PCWSTR devinst = L"HID\\VID_413C&PID_2105\\6&22CE0F66&0&0000";
    HDEVINFO hinfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, devinst, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);
    if (hinfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        error(GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    SP_DEVINFO_DATA dinfo;
    dinfo.cbSize = sizeof(dinfo);
    int ix = 0;
    while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hinfo, ix++, &dinfo))
    {
        wprintf(L"Match\n");
    }

    error(GetLastError());

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hinfo);
    return 0;
}
```

With output:

```
Match
103: No more data is available.
```

Comment: The DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES was the missing part for me. From MSDN documentation I understood that only DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE was necessary, but that gave error 87 (bad arguments).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you're misunderstanding `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`.

There are a few different types of `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` messages-- for a volume, for a handle, for a device interface. I'm guessing you're talking about the DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE variety. In this case, the `dbcc_name` field of the `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` structure will contain the "device interface path".

The "device interface path" is NOT the same as a "device instance ID".

If you want to know more information about this device, you should enumerate all device **interfaces** by this device interface GUID (through SetupDiGetClassDevs with DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE), and compare the dbcc_name to the strings retrieved by `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces`.